# Help Needed! How do I attach a color sensor to a 2WD robot and use it to control its movement?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, pins, shields, robotics

I'm relatively new to the world of Arduino, so don't be frustrated if I ask questions that could be silly. This project has a deadline, so any input is appreciated.

THE PROJECT:

I am planning to build a 2WD vehicle, with an arm using 2 servos, and a TCS3200 color sensor. The goal is to make the robot avoid obstacles while simultaneously searching for a GREEN colored object (using the color sensor). After finding the GREEN object, it would stop and use the robotic claw to grab the object. Finally, it would continue to avoid obstacles until you reach a RED colored area. It would drop the object and start again.

QUESTIONS:

That said, I have some questions about the use of different sensors to control a robot (do not hesitate to put any input that may be useful)

1) How would you connect it to the sensor shield considering the other components? Could you use analog pins or (converting digital to analog) or use fewer pins? (I just need Green and Red)

2) How would make it so that the Arduino receives data from both sensors at the same time? How can I make both sensors control the same two motors?

WIRING:
[image: wiring exactly the same]
[image: bigger image]

NOTE: in the second image the ultrasonic sensor should be connected to the bottom right pins

EDIT:
@Peter Paul Kiefer---Could you please elaborate on how I can achieve for both sensors to control the same motors at the same time? Link to website where it is explained?

@jsotola 1) what do you mean by output? 2) I know that, I just want for the Arduino Uno to receive data from both the Ultrasonic and color detection at the same time. Using the data, I want the Arduino to control the motors to avoid obstacles, while using the color sensor to detect the GREEN object(at the same time)

The sensor It is called a TCS3200 color sensor by the way, and seems to only use digital pins. I am connecting it to the sensor sensor shield along with other things. (refer to images in the first post)This is how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: what type of output does the color sensor use?

Comment: `How can I make both sensors control the same two motors?` ... the sensors do not control the motors ... the arduino controls the motors ... the sensors only provide data to the arduino

Comment: You do not need to use an "PWM"-pin. The sensor reacts on different colors by changing the frequency at the OUT pin. The S2 S3 inputs are used to specify the color your want to measure. You can use S0 and S1 to switch to different frequency ranges. Use the ` pulseIn(sensorOut, LOW);` function to read the LOW pulse length of the  emitted frequency to get the intensity of the light of the chosen color. You could  use the `pulseIn` function to read Time of Fly  for the HC-SR04 too. You can use both sensors to read the values sequentially in the loop method.

Comment: Here are some further infos: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/arduino-color-sensor-tcs230-tcs3200/ I found it by goggel the words "TCS3200" "color" "sensor".

Comment: How did you go with this? Any progress?